# how to stop CSS animation without javascript

Tags: javascript, animation, css, transition

[This is the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTG42/). What I would like is stop the box when it reaches its end position. I know there is a transition function available also but that does not seem to work. Are all animation functions type also available for transition? I am using rotate function in my actual work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set `animation-iteration-count` to 1. A value of `infinite` causes the animation to be repeated infinitely. And remember to style the object the way it should be AFTER the animation (`top: 200px;`).

I've updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nTG42/2/

More information is provide by the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/css_animations

Comment: can you give help with this one http://mytimesheet.us/demo/speedometer.html. It is a rotating one. Can it be done the same way?

Comment: Sure! All you need to do is to apply `transform: rotate(180deg);` to the needle - otherwise the animation works fine, but after it's complete the original state is restored.

Comment: this this `@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
 -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
}` which didn't work. I am still working on it.

Comment: You don't need to edit the animation, that part is fine. You need to add this to the styles for `#needle`, e.g. right after `#needle {` in your css file.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the infinite from `animation:mymove infinite;` and set the final place as top:200px. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nTG42/4/)